# tfrecord VarLenFeature read error

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I tested to write dynamic numbers of variables into tfrecord. But the VarLenFeature cannot read them correctly.

My writing codes are

```
def test_write():
  writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfrecord')

  for i in range(3):
    val_list = []
    for j in range(i+1):
      val_list.append(i+j)
    feature_dict = {
      'val': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=val_list)),
    }

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

  writer.close()
```

The reading codes are

```
def parse_test(example):
  features = {
    'val': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)
  }
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example, features)

  return parsed_features

def test_read():
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['test.tfrecord'])
  dataset = dataset.map(parse_test)
  dataset = dataset.batch(1)

  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  feature_dict =  iterator.get_next()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(3):
      curr_dict = sess.run(feature_dict)
      print([curr_dict['val']])
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Slice_Indices_val:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample:1", shape=(?,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=Tensor("ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_Shape_val:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

However, if I do not use dataset, but just tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator. The program works without problem. This code is as below

```
def test_read2():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    for serialized_example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('test.tfrecord'):
      features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
        features={
          'val': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
        }
      )

      temp = features['val']

      values = sess.run(temp)
      print(values)
```

This code successfully print out

```
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0]], dtype=int64), values=array([0], dtype=int64), dense_shape=array([1], dtype=int64))
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0],
       [1]], dtype=int64), values=array([1, 2], dtype=int64), dense_shape=array([2], dtype=int64))
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]], dtype=int64), values=array([2, 3, 4], dtype=int64), dense_shape=array([3], dtype=int64))
```

However, I am still hoping to use the dataset structure to deal with the VarLenFeature. Is there anything wrong with my reading codes? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need do this in the function parse_test()

```
def parse_test(example):
  features = {
    'val': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)
  }
  parsed_dict = tf.parse_example(example, features)
  parsed_features = {"val": tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_dict ["val"], default_value=0)}

  return parsed_features
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation around your proposed solution?